# AWS S3 GET request fallback to a different virtual folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3

Does anyone know if it is possible to set a rule or some kind of config to S3 server which will allow fallback to a different virtual folder if some resource is not found on given path?

Here is an example:

Url that is called is `https://bucket.s3.domain/virtual-folder/1/res.ext`. If `res.ext` can not be found in virtual folder `1` I would like it to redirect it to it's parent `https://bucket.s3.domain/virtual-folder/res.ext` Parent will contain default versions of resources. So the idea is if you can't find specific resource S3 should automatically return the default one.

I have made some research but all I get is about website redirections. What I need here is a raw resources that devices will pull in a single request, and S3 will take care of everything.

Is this stuff even possible?

Thanks,
Ante.

Comment: First of all S3 is not a server it is a Object based storage. Also S3 does not take care of any thing for you it only stores object you have to mention this condition of fall back in your script. The redirect for S3 is when you are hosting a static website in S3.

Comment: @error2007s I thought it would be the case but I was hoping you can make some kind of config (like policy) where you might put some rules. Nevertheless thanks for your comment.

Comment: You would have to write the layer that you describe.

Comment: What Kind of layer you have in mind @jbird? 'coz if I need to make like a script on some server it doesn't seem like a good idea.Then I will create potential bottle neck.

Comment: It's entirely possible with well-written, tight code such as is found in Varnish to proxy requests through EC2 to S3 and manipulate them in ways like this without worrying about bottlenecks until you are handling millions of requests per day.  It is also possible with S3 redirect rules to redirect /foo/bar/baz.jpg to /foo/baz.jpg if the former does not exist if the set of possible paths is small enough that you can store enough rules to handle them... but those solutions use *redirects* which, even though you used that word, is not what you want, because it means 2 requests.

Comment: @AnteBraovic I had in mind a basic REST layer. If a request for an object returned a 404 your REST service would react and change the S3 object's key based on your rules and retry the request. It's just an S3 proxy with the added rules.

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys. It seems that this can not be done in a way I've described. I'll probably use request fallback from client because I don't expect to have this situation in a significant percentage, and I do expect to have high number of requests. Once more thanks.

Comment: @jbird it can be done now! See my answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible now with new feature is S3! You have to set your bucket to be a static website (which will require you to change a URL you use to asses files) and then set a following redirection rule:

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals>artist-media/staging</KeyPrefixEquals>
            <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>403</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <HostName>someotherbucket.s3.amazonaws.com</HostName>
            <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>artist-media/production</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

What I wanted to do is to serve pictures from a developer bucket if a file was uploaded and if not then fallback to the production one.
For that reason I have to use `KeyPrefixEquals` and `ReplaceKeyPrefixWith`, you can just remove it if this is not what you need.
As for the redirection itself the rule catches 403 error (denied because file is missing. If you make the bucket public you probably need to use 404 there) and then just sets a new host (bucket URL) to point to.

Comment: When you say "need to use 40 here" do you mean `400`?

Comment: @GunarGessner it's been a while :D But I meant 404, so when a bucket is public and a file is missing, you will probably need to match error code 404 instead of 403. Probably, I'm not sure and have no way of checking at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to host an SPA, you can now configure an error document on the S3 bucket.

---

To configure an error document

1. Create an error document, for example `404.html`.
2. Save the error document file locally.

   The error document name is case sensitive and must exactly match the name that you enter when you enable static website hosting. For example, if you enter `404.html` for the Error document name in the Static website hosting dialog box, your error document file name must also be `404.html`.
3. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon S3 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/.
4. In the Buckets list, choose the name of the bucket that you want to use to host a static website.
5. Enable static website hosting for your bucket, and enter the exact name of your error document (for example, `404.html`). For more information, see [Enabling website hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/EnableWebsiteHosting.html).

   After enabling static website hosting, proceed to step 6.
6. To upload the error document to your bucket, do one of the following:

   - Drag and drop the error document file into the console bucket listing.
   - Choose Upload, and follow the prompts to choose and upload the index file.

   For step-by-step instructions, see [Uploading objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/upload-objects.html).

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/CustomErrorDocSupport.html#custom-error-document